# not understanding rest

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

Im not understanding something about rest web services. When you do get, post etc how and where is it storing the information? Im just really not getting it at all compared to just doing a normal database query why would you use a webservice?

**From Wiki:**

REST consist of clients and servers. Clients initiate requests to servers; servers process requests and return appropriate responses. Requests and responses are built around the transfer of representations of resources.

I get the first part but im stuck on the second part?

POST is one of many request methods supported by the HTTP protocol used by the World Wide Web. The POST request method is used when the client needs to send data to the server as part of the request, such as submitting a completed form.

Why not just use a database?

Turning wcf into a rest service seems like such a hard task and im missing its importance even getting wcf to work is such a hard task with service contracts, datacontracts and datamembers then configuring endpoints base addresses etc etc. The only thing I have come to understand is that the server can or could process something for you’re instead of the client processing it but wouldn’t that just be a burden on the server? And possibiliy reusing the service but im not sure how because every situation is different?

Comment: *Why not just use a database?* Well, REST over HTTP can be used by anybody anywhere on the planet as long as their firewall allows HTTP. Definitely not so for databases.

Comment: In my exploration to learn about REST I found a youtube channel by Apigee, www.youtube.com/apigee they have amazing videos covering many aspects of REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is used to transfer data across a network that may not have access to the database. It's not about storage. Not everything can directly connect to your database and needs a communication layer. A WCF RESTful webservice is VERY easy to build. Use the online template, not just the built in WCF one, when you create a new project if you need help getting it going.

Answer (score 3):

> Why not just use a database?

Because a database **just stores data**, and the principles of REST can be used to build a scalable, evolvable system that offers read/write access to the data held within it **across a network**.